# How do I bind onerror to an image inside a Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to bind an event to the `onerror` of an image inside my view.

`onerror` doesn't bubble up so I can't use `events: { 'error img' : 'imgEvent_' }`.

How can I bind this to maybe something like `this.el.querySelector('img').on('error, imgEvent_, this);`?

No inline HTML please.

Forgot to mention... I don't use any DOM libraries so no jQuery and such.

I did this:

```
this.el.queryelector('img').onerror = this.myFunction_;
```

My problem now is that within `this.myFunction_`, `this` is actually the `img` element... I still need to access the `this` where `myFunction_` resides. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you use any DOM library (jQuery, Zepto, etc.)?

Comment: Forgot to mention... I don't use any DOM libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can't bind onerror in events map, because here Backbone.js delegate events from document to specified element (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
events: { 'error img': 'callaback' }
```

Mean something like this:

```
$(document).on('error', 'img', callback);
```

Have document onerror? And can it be delegated to img?

I recommend you to bind it yourself:

```
this.$('img').on('error', callback);
```

P.S. Excuse me for my English.

Comment: Forgot to say, I don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the image element from the target property of the [first argument given to the error function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error). You can bind the method to your View using [Underscore's bind method](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

```
this.el.queryelector('img').onerror = _.bind(function(error){
    var img = error.target;
    this.myFunction_();
}, this);
```

If you just need `myFunction` to always refer to the view and don't care about the image or whatever, you can use

```
this.el.queryelector('img').onerror = _.bind(this.myFunction_, this);
```

or [Underscore's bindAll method](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll).

```
_.bindAll(this, 'myFunction_');
this.el.queryelector('img').onerror = this.myFunction_;
```